# Autoinstalling Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: iso, cloud-init

I'm searching for a method to make a bootable USB that automatically installs Ubuntu 22.04 with a desktop environment.
I had a [setup](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Make-Ubuntu-Autoinstall-ISO-with-Cloud-init-2213/) for Ubuntu Server 20.04 (installing gnome during the setup) by using cloud-init and [ubuntu-autoinstall-generator](https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator).

However, that ubuntu-autoinstall-generator does no longer work with the changed ISO layout of Ubuntu 22.04 server. I've tried to manually pack the user-data into the ISO, but I had no luck. Either the installer just started as if there were no user-data YAML ([ubuntu-22-04-autoinstall-method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403686/ubuntu-22-04-autoinstall-method) or [how-to-make-ubuntu-autoinstall-iso-with-cloud-init-in-ubuntu-21-10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390827/how-to-make-ubuntu-autoinstall-iso-with-cloud-init-in-ubuntu-21-10)) or the installer crashed at some point ([this 20.04 gist](https://gist.github.com/s3rj1k/55b10cd20f31542046018fcce32f103e) combined with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390827/how-to-make-ubuntu-autoinstall-iso-with-cloud-init-in-ubuntu-21-10)).

I found [this](https://github.com/mwhudson/livefs-editor#add-autoinstall-config) Python tool, but the tool itself crashes before doing anything useful, no matter how I installed it.

Does anyone have a reliable method of creating auto installing ISOs for Ubuntu Server 22.04?

To be clear: I want a desktop environment in the end, so using the Desktop version of Ubuntu would be beneficial. However, I wasn't able to get preseed working on 20.04, so I switched to the server image and cloud-init. And I would prefer to stay with cloud-init, as it seems to be more future-proof. (and I have cloud-init already configured)

Comment: In 22.04, Ubuntu Desktop uses the older Ubiquity installer, compatible with preseed files. Ubuntu Server uses the newer subiquity installer, compatible with cloud-init YAML. Don't mix them up. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1411360/edit): It's currently unclear if you want to install Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server. If a method doesn't work for you "*it did not work*" is too vague to offer useful advice -- perhaps you skipped a step or made some other mistake. Try to limit your question to a single specific issue or question; you will get better answers.

Comment: The question to me is too broad for an answer. We would rather see errors you face. So 2 links to get started: This is the official document on this: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall Here is very extensive method https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Make-Ubuntu-Autoinstall-ISO-with-Cloud-init-2213/ (too large for an answer).

Comment: and a script https://gist.github.com/s3rj1k/55b10cd20f31542046018fcce32f103e  BUT do change the URL and version to an official source and not volia.net. That ISO could have been changed.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind, but the guides you linked are for Ubuntu 20.04, which I don't have any problems with. Since 20.10, the installer was changed, breaking all off the methods you have mentioned.

Comment: @McToel that is a matter of replacing 20.04 to 22.04 (and as I said above: do not trust that URL, use the official one). The links are for the NEW method but using 20.04